# Is this equals implementation ok?

Tags: java, equals

I have a cache implementation for which i have the KeyObject implemented

So the cache is  `HashMap<KeyObject , List<SomeObjects>>`

This KeyObject class ,say it has 2 variable a,b ;

```
class KeyObject {
    MyObject a;
    AnotherMyObject b;

    KeyObject(MyObject a, AnotherMyObject b){
          this.a = prop1 ; this.b= prop2;
    }
}
```

Is it ok , that i have equals method implemented depending on the properties on MyObject and AnotherMyObject..

Say something like this

```
public boolean equals(Object keyObject){
    if(keyObject.isSomeType() && this.a.isSomeType(){
       return keyObject.a.equals(this.a)
    }
    else{
        return keyObject.a.equals(this.a) && keyObject.b.equals(this.b)
    }
}
```

Is the equals implemenation like above a common practice?

Thanks

Comment: thanks for editing. I was trying to do that before you got it done!!

Comment: Have you seen the [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: In any case, you must also implement `hashCode` and make sure it returns the same value for equal objects.

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

1. Check if the object you are comparing to is null.
2. Use `instanceof` to make sure the other object is of the right type.
3. Type cast the other `Object` into a `KeyObject` before testing for equality.

So something like this:

```
// Override annotation gives you bonus points :)
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    if (!(other instanceof KeyObject))
        return false;

    KeyObject keyObject = (KeyObject) other;

    // I'm not exactly sure what this line is doing
    // but I assume it's part of your program.
    if(keyObject.isSomeType() && this.a.isSomeType()
        return keyObject.a.equals(this.a);
    else
        return keyObject.a.equals(this.a) && keyObject.b.equals(this.b);
}
```

Comment: Use `instanceof` sure, but maybe not _instead of_ `isSomeType()`.  If `isSomeType()` contains important business logic, it is entirely appropriate to have it in `equals()`.  Your example is correct.

Comment: Yeah sorry not instead of, I missed what that code did the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

I found this guide when googling: [Implementing equals](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17)

> - object fields, including collections : use equals
> - type-safe enumerations : use either equals or == (they amount to the same thing, in this case)
> - possibly-null object fields : use both == and equals
> - array fields : use Arrays.equals
> - primitive fields other than float or double : use ==
> - float : convert to int using Float.floatToIntBits, then use ==
> - double :  convert to long using Double.doubleToLongBits, then use ==

I think these guidelines are pretty much all your need.